# How switching to another web page jquery flask

Tags: jquery, python, html, flask-login, flask-restful

I made a script that allows a user to login I used python flask microframework jquery but the problem that if I filled the fields user and password it will not have a passage to another page which I have already specified in the method if the data are loginuser correctent. And the second problem is the appraition data in the url.

login1.html

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<!--[if (gte IE 9)|!(IE)]><!--> <html lang="en"> <!--<![endif]-->
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>login</title>
<link href="static/css/style.css" rel="stylesheet">
<script src="static/js/jquery-1.9.0.js"></script>
<script src="static/js/script.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<div class="container">
    <section id="content">
        <form class="form-signin" role="form">
            <h1>Login Form</h1>
            <div> 

                <input type="text" id="txtUsername" placeholder="Username" name="username"  required autofocus>
                                <input type="password" id="txtPassword" placeholder="Password" name="password" required autofocus>
                               <input class="btn btn-default" type="submit" value="Login">

                      </div>
        </form><!-- form -->
        {% if error %}
                    <p class="error"><strong>Error:</strong> {{ error }}
                {% endif %}
    </section><!-- content -->

</div><!-- container -->
</body>
</html>
```

```js
$(function(){
    $('submit').click(function(){

                var user = $('#txtUsername').val();
        var pass = $('#txtPassword').val();
        $.ajax({
            url: '/loginuser',
            data: $('form').serialize(),
            type: 'POST',
            success: function(response){
                console.log(response);
            },
            error: function(error){
                console.log(error);
            }
        });
    });
});
```

this script.js.
and app.py

```html
@APP.route('/login')
def login1():

      return render_template('login1.html')


# route for handling the login page logic

@APP.route('/loginuser', methods=['POST'])
def login():

    error = None
    con = mdb.connect('localhost','testuser', 'test623', 'secure')
    #con= mdb.connect(host="x.x.x.x", port=3306, passwd="root", db="se")
    cur = con.cursor()
    cur.execute("SELECT * FROM ADMIN")
    rows = cur.fetchall()
    login=False
    ########recuperer la liste des admin de la BD ADMIN
    for row in rows:
             if request.form['username'] == row[0] and  request.form['password'] == row[1]:
                login=True


    con.close
    if login ==False:
             error = 'Invalid Credentials. Please try again.'
             return render_template('login1.html', error=error)

    else:
             return render_template('mon.html', error=error)
```

Answer (score 0):

As far as I understand the question, you shouldn't use AJAX here.
When using AJAX you will not be redirected to a new page rendered by

```
@APP.route('/loginuser', methods=['POST'])
def login():
   ...
```

You will rather get this page in AJAX response and can access it in your `success` callback (first parameter).

If you want to go with AJAX here, you should change your `login` response to something, that can be conveniently consumed by JavaScript, for example JSON response, that contains login attempt result. Something like

```
{
    "result": "success",
    "details": "User has been successfully logged in"
}
```

or

```
{
    "result": "error",
    "details": "Login or password is incorrect"
}
```

You should return this JSON instead of your login form template

(instead of this)

```
         return render_template('login1.html', error=error)
```

Then parse it in your success/error callback and make a decision on how to display this information to the user.

```
$(function(){
    $('submit').click(function(){

                var user = $('#txtUsername').val();
        var pass = $('#txtPassword').val();
        $.ajax({
            url: '/loginuser',
            data: $('form').serialize(),
            type: 'POST',
            dataType: 'json',
            success: function(response){
                if (response.result == "success") {
                    alert("You have been logged in!");
                } else {
                    alert(result.details);
                    // You can do something much more complex than 'alert' here
                    // E.g, you can add a DOM element with an error message
                }
            },
            error: function(error){
                console.log(error);
            }
        });
    });
});
```

Sorry, but I could not understand your second question...

Comment: Leonvich is what I have to change the .js file as you said or how I can do to make the call from another page can succeed. thanks

Comment: I tried to say that if you use AJAX to make a call, it does NOT refresh the current page in browser. It only retrieves the HTTP response from your server and gives you access to it in your ```success``` and ```error``` functions.  So, if you just make an AJAX call, you'll not see any changes on the page. You should perform them explicitly in your ```success``` callback by writing some JS code. And as I said, HTML response is not a best format for passing data via AJAX, in this case it's better to use JSON or XML.

Answer (score 0):

Well, you cannot select an element just by attribute only. The ajax function is not called. Give the submit button an id and it will work.

For example:

change this line

```
<input class="btn btn-default" type="submit" value="Login">
```

to

```
<input class="btn btn-default" id = "submitButton" type="submit" value="Login">
```

and 
the javascript to

```
 $('#submitButton').click(function(){.... });
```

Comment: I add id to the button but I can't switch to anaother page.@gopiariv